# How to trigger an event on a dynamically changing button?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button which dynamically changes `id` (`main-btn-0` through `main-btn-3`) . I want it to, when clicked, trigger a click on another button that corresponds to the `test-btn-X` id.

So I have a total of 5 buttons here. One "main" button that dynamically changes `id`, and 4 buttons with ids' `test-btn-0` through `test-btn-3`.

So when the main button has an id of `main-btn-0` it should trigger a click on `test-btn-0`, `main-btn-1` triggers `test-btn-1`, and so on.

This is what I have tried so far, but doesn't work:

```
$(document).on('click', '#main-btn-0', function(){
    $('#test-btn-0').click();
});

$(document).on('click', '#main-btn-1', function(){
    $('#test-btn-1').click();
}); 

$(document).on('click', '#main-btn-2', function(){
    $('#test-btn-2').click();
}); 

$(document).on('click', '#main-btn-3', function(){
    $('#test-btn-3').click();
});
```

What am I missing here?

Also, is there a way to just have 1 function instead of 4?

Thanks.

Comment: Corrected some errors.

Comment: yon can create one function and pass that values(0,1,..) into that, so depends on that you can call the click()

Comment: Are the buttons dynamically generated? Why the use of `on()`?

Comment: Does `'#test-btn-0',.... n` contains any click events bound with them?

Comment: @haim770 There's nothing wrong in event delegation here. :)

Comment: @haim770, no. The buttons are not dynamically generated. Only the "main" buttons ID changes.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy, I didn't mean there's something 'wrong', I did want to understand the exact case.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy, no.

Comment: @Chris `.click()` will invoke the click event bound with that particular element. What are you trying to do exactly? what is the nature of the elements with id '#test-btn-0'...N

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could give the buttons a class "main-btn" instead and then a data-id of "1", "2" etc.

```
<button class="main-btn" data-id="1">main 1</button>
```

then the code would be something like:

```
$(document).on('click',".main-btn",function(){
    $(".test-btn-" + $(this).data("id")).click();
})
```

Here is a test with it:
http://jsfiddle.net/xyn4k784/

Answer (score 0):

The fact that the ids change is not a problem, as long as you know what they are at the time the dom is ready: in this case, you can install an event listener to the click event and then, inside the function, check for the actual id at the time the button get clicked to do your thing.

To read the id you'll have to use attr:

```
$(this).attr("id");
```

If instead you want to be able to select the buttons at any time, you could use different way of finding them, after all ids are only the most trivial selectors but by far not the only one.

You could, for example, give each of them a specific class. I'll add another couple of these as soon as I check the specification for the css selectors.

Edit: For example `$('*[id|=main]')` should match any element whose id starts with "main" followed by a '-'.